# can't create file from nginx to docker-gen

Tags: docker, jwilder-nginx-proxy, docker-gen

I'm using [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) in order to have a project in my domain.tld and one in api.domain.tld. I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/) and I'm facing a problem with my custom `default.conf`. First I'm running the image from my project

```
docker container run -d --expose 80 --expose 443 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.tld -e VIRTUAL_PORT=80,443 --name my_site my_site
```

then I'm running nginx-proxy:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /home/myuser/docker_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -v /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:rw -v /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf -v /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf --name proxy jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

but I'm receiving the below error:

```
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
    forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
    forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
    dockergen.1 | 2017/10/16 18:56:26 Unable to create dest file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf: rename /etc/nginx/conf.d/docker-gen123335743 /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf: device or resource busy
    forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5100
    forego     | sending SIGTERM to nginx.1
    forego     | sending SIGTERM to dockergen.1
```

`default.conf` file:

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
resolver 168.63.129.16;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 503;
}
# domain.tld
upstream domain.tld {
                ## Can be connect with "bridge" network
            # my_site
            server 172.17.0.3:80;
}
server {
    server_name domain.tld;
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    listen 443;

    root /var/www/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-$";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_pass http://domain.tld;
    }
}
```

My main site is implemented in Laravel.

I'm a bit confused because I couldn't find any relative information neither in google nor in GitHub issues.

Is something wrong with my `default.conf` file or I didn't set the containers right?

Thank you.

Comment: you're mounting the file as read only ( :ro ). Try mounting it without any extra flags

Comment: no the error is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the name of the config file. I replaced `default.conf` with `my_proxy.conf` and it worked.